# Tell Resharper that a lambda argument is not null

Tags: c#, lambda, resharper

I have a method like this:

```
void Foo(object x, Action<object> f) {
    if (x != null)
        f (x);
}
```

And I would like to use it like this:

```
void Bar () {
    Foo ("baz", g => g.ToString());
    Foo (null, g => g.ToString());
}
```

But Resharper is complaining that the g in the lambdas might be null. Is it possibile to annotate the method to tell Resharper that g will never be null?

Comment: I don't get that warning from Resharper.  I must have it turned off, because it would be very annoying.  I'll see if I can figure out which setting handles this.

Comment: You must enable the pessimistic checker

Comment: I am also not getting any warning , I didn't turn off anything

Comment: @Aswartha you must enable the stricter null checking  explicitly

Comment: There is now a feature request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-429178

Comment: Interesting. I haven't tried the pessimistic checker, so will turn that on today and give it a shot. Out of curiosity, how would you anticipate telling this to R#? Where would the attribute live? Could it reuse one of the existing annotations attributes?

Answer (score -1):

Using ReSharper, when you're on a line that could be improved, a yellow bulb should appear at the left of the code editor, if you click it, there is an "Inspection:..." option, click it, and then click on `Disable once with comment`, a comment like:

> // ReSharper disable once ...

should appear just before the line. You could, find the hard way to specifically tell "It isn't gonna be null", or just make it ignore the problem. I hope it helped.

**EDIT:** I want to say that im using Licensed ReSharper 9, just for specifying.

Comment: This is how to suppress it, not how to tell resharper that the value is not null